# How to find the subgroups of S4 generated by these sets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

How do I find the subgroups of $S4$ generated by these sets in each case?

- $A = {(1,3),(1,2,3,4)}$
- $B = {(1,2,4),(2,3,4)}$
- $C = {(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)}$

Comment: Do you know what "generate" means?

Comment: By doing the computations. There are not actually that many of them to do.

Comment: Thanks to Babak S. for the answer. Also, thanks to Secret Math and Tobias Kildetoft for the rude comments.

Comment: @MartínMas: the first example shows that the claim "a subgroup of $S_n$ generated by a $n$-cycle and a transposition is $S_n$ itself" is wrong if $n$ is not prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am giving you some points about A. I hope you can use them well. Let $a=(1,3),~b=(1,2,3,4)$ , we know that $$S_4=\langle x,y\mid x^2=y^4=(xy)^3=1\rangle$$ and beause of the final relation inside the presentation, we can show every element of $S_4$ as $x^iy^j$ where $i=0,1,~~j=0,1,2,3$. Here, $|a|=2,~~|b|=4$ and $$a^2=id\\ b^2=(1,3)(2,4)\\ b^3=(1,4,3,2)\\ab^2=(2,4)\\ab^3=(1,2)(3,4)\\ ab=(1,4)(2,3)$$ This means that $\langle a,b\rangle=\{id,a,b,ab,ab^2,ab^3,b^2,b^3\}$

Comment: I'm not pretty sure about how to do it with $B$. Do I have to compute $a^2$, $b^2$, $ab$, $a^{2} b$ and $ab^{2}$ ? Why do I haven't got to compute $ba$, $b a^{2}$ and $b a^2$?

Also, is $C = S_4$?

Comment: Don't we simply have $\langle A \rangle \cong D_8$ ?