# Find All Subgroups in $S_4$ with Order $8$

Tags: group-theory

[See page 4 for the proof on the existence of a Sylow $p$-subgroup](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/sylowpf.pdf)

I followed the algorithm presented in the proof to build a subgroup with $8$ elements:
$$(1), \, (1 2), \, (3 4), \, (1 2)(3 4), \, (1 3)(2 4), \, (1 4)(2 3), \, (1 4 2 3), \, (1 3 2 4)$$
To summarize, I began with $H_1 = \{ \, (1), \, (1 2) \, \}$ and from the normalizers of $H_1$, pick out two additional elements to make $H_2$, which has four elements.  Then from the normalizers of $H_2$, pick out four more elements to complete the subset ....

It was good exercise to see how the proof works, but it took so darn long.  Now, I still need to conjugate my initial subgroup to find the other subgroups.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530062/how-to-find-the-subgroups-of-s4-generated-by-these-sets), and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379841/how-to-enumerate-subgroups-of-each-order-of-s-4-by-hand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $S_4$ you may notice that the action of the dihedral group $D_8$ on the 4 vertices of the square gives an embedding $D_8\to S_4$, which must be a Sylow 2-subgroup. This subgroup is not normal, so using Sylow theory you conclude there are 3 conjugates. These are not hard to write down.

Comment: TY, I did not realize that they are related ....